# How can I always tell which instance I'm dealing with?

Tags: isv, org

This is a Q & A question for people (especially ISV's like us) who deal with lots of different orgs.

It's often critical, in a single screen (like a managed package install process) to be 100% sure which org you are dealing with. You can look at instance name, or go to your org or user details page, but instance name isn't specific enough when you deal with dozens of orgs, and the org/user details pages are a click away.

So, how do you manage this?

Answer (score 12):

I think the simplest and most efficient way to do this is to just modify your last name in the org:

[image]

Comment: This is an excellent idea as well and something I utilize when jumping between environments.

Comment: Love this! Never thought to do that...

Comment: +1 - My technique as well, but I put it with my first name.  "Tom (tc2) Collins" on my current org.  Can't state advantages or disadvantages over modifying first/lastname, but it's worked great for me.

Comment: Definitely the simplest, +1! The only plus with images is that they're prominent and I'm able to color-code my instances, etc.

Comment: I put an idea up on ideas ages about about colouring the skin differently for sandboxes, would be handy

Comment: Yeah, i guess putting the org in your First/Last name works.  Until you start refreshing sandboxes.  Pretty soon you'll end up with "(prod)" in the name of your user in all sandboxes and it won't help you anymore.

I like LaceySnr's idea above, and I think Chrome has an addin to differentiate PROD from sandbox in the tabs

Answer (score 8):

This isn't going to be a big help right out of the box for the type of situation you are experiencing, but I really like Chrome plugins like [Salesforce.com Sandbox Favicon Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforcecom-sandbox-fav/nkfllgjejgfgcddfccnijhndhdmjkamf)
. Now, this uses the URL to impose an S over the cloud logo (so test.salesforce.com is distinguished from login.salesforce.com), but you may be able to use this extension as inspiration for something like what you want to do as well.

I know it is a long shot and it would require a decent amount of effort on your part (to create a Chrome/Firefox plugin for this sort of thing), but this may be a long term solution for you if this type of thing really needs to be resolved. I am not 100% sure how you could utilize functionality like this right now, but figured I would share just in case. For now, your method works much better as long as you actually switch to the tab and look at the image.

Answer (score 2):

I wish there was an out-of-the-box option to show instance or username on every page, but alas, (still) not yet.

There are a few ways people can do this, but this is what we do. It may not be a workable solution if you are dealing with customer orgs where you can't create/edit apps, but for dealing with lots of internal orgs it works great.

Create an app image, or take your existing one. For each one of your orgs, edit the image in your favorite image editor and insert the name of the org into it. For example:

[image: App Image]

Then, either create or edit the default app you use in that org, and make this image the app image. Then, every screen you are on, you can always be 100% sure you are in the right org:

[image]

Hope this helps.